# Basic problems in python

Tags: python

How can you store output of any piece of code into a new variable?

```
number=range(20)
for number in number:
    if number%2!=0:
        print(number)
```

Like I want to store the output of this in a new variable called 'odd_numbers'.

Comment: `odd_numbers = [i for i in number if i%2 !=0]`

Comment: What, exactly, do you mean by the output? Whatever is printed to standard out? Why do you want to do this? You probably  should be creating some result instead of merely printing things.

Answer (score 1):

Use a list comprehension:

```
number = range(20)
odd_numbers = [i for i in number if i%2]
```

Or append them:

```
number = range(20)
odd_numbers = []
for i in number:
    if i % 2:
        odd_numbers.append(i)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
odd_numbers = []
for i in range(20):
   if i%2 != 0:
       odd_number.append(i)
```

Any time you want to store something you should create bucket and put values into that bucket (variable, list, dict, set).

Comment: "bucket" isn't really standard terminology. This would more commonly be called a "container"